# In PostGIS is it possible to create a View with a unique ID?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

When I create a view in PostGIS is there any way to add a unique ID to that view? Just like the "gid" field in any other PostGIS table?

*Edit:* Sorry I should have included this in the original post. I am using PostGresql 9.0 and PostGIS 1.5.

Ando

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to use the row_number() function as a column in your view. This works for Postgres 8.4 or higher.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_to_sort_by ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER,
    Col1, Col2
  FROM table_name
) myview_name
```

This should work in most databases including SQL Server, Oracle, and MySQL.

Comment: Cool - I'll give it ago and get back to you.

Comment: You also can do  `row_number() OVER() AS "id"` without `ORDER` over column

Comment: This is usually a *very* poor design decision, as `row_number` is effectively a random value. You can't depend on it being consistent between `SELECT`s, particularly when the underlying data changes.

Comment: @jpmc - by its very nature a view will change if its underlying data changes. A reliable ID isn't part of the question requirements. Some GISs simply require a unique ID for each feature just to load the layer (e.g. ArcMap).

Comment: I would not trust ArcMap to function properly with an inconsistent ID. How do you know it doesn't requery the database when you pan but not refresh the attribute table? Then you'd have a mismatch trying to select features.

Answer (score 6):

For older versions of PostgreSQL (<= 8.3), here is another solution. In this example, I use another column name `vid` for "view ID".

First, create a sequence. Use `CYCLE` so that it will loop in the event you reach the end of the sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myview_vid_seq CYCLE;
```

Now, create a VIEW that uses the sequence:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS 
 SELECT nextval('myview_vid_seq'::regclass) AS vid, mytable.*
 FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I haven't been back into work to try these suggestions yet. But the solution you have suggested is this only for Postgresql versions <= 8.3? I am running Postresql 9.0 and PostGIS 1.5.

Comment: For your system, both this and geographika's answer should work. It would be a good performance test to see which one is faster. I've had to do what you ask in your question to view data in QGIS, so I'm guessing you are in a similar situation.

Comment: Identical situation I would say - Trying to combine a few layers in a view and require an unique id for QGIS.