# Can I save a newly created Intersection layer directly into a Spatialite database in QGIS without importing?

Tags: qgis, intersection, spatialite

I have a point layer (xyz_coordinates_UTM33N) and a polygon layer (section1) in a SpatiaLite database.

[image: My SpatialLite database]

I wish to extract the points within the polygon to a new layer, and I want that layer stored in the database.
[image: Section 1]

I know I can create a new layer by using the Intersection tool, but how can I save the new point file without first saving it as a shapefile and then importing it into the database?

[image: Intersection settings]

Using the "Save to SpatiaLite table" only creates a new database!
How can I accomplish this without all the extra steps?

Comment: I tried and set the sqlite db as output, and I get an error  `ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.` is it same as you ?

Comment: No. When I chose the sqlite db as output I did get an output that appears in the Layers Panel but no points are visible in the Map View.

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using ?

Comment: 2.18.13. No features from the original point file is in the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You use the QspatiaLite plugin for QGIS. If will handle the creation of the spatial view. I use a building as an example of a polygon.

[image]

In the dialog you can write the SQL code doing the spatial join:

```
select *
from point p
inner join building b on st_within(p.geometry, b.geometry);
```

[image]

The spatiale view is dynamic in regard to it base layers. If you add point or a building the spatial view will be updated when you hit the QGIS refresh button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You got to create a **view** (="dynamic" query corresponding to your intersection) directly in the spatialite database.

Check [Can QGIS read spatialite views ?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/can-qgis-read-spatialite-views?rq=1)