# QGIS returns "Invalid Layer" message when trying to add PostGIS view?

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-view

I'm new to Postgis and QGIS. I created a view defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pupr.vstudentmuni AS 
 SELECT m.id AS munid, m.name AS muname, m.geom, s.code, 
    (s.name::text || ' '::text) || s.lastname::text AS fullname
   FROM pupr.municipio m, pupr.student_location l, pupr.student s
  WHERE st_within(l.geom, m.geom) AND s.code = l.code;
```

in PostgreSQL. Trying to add this view to QGIS returns the following error...

```
"Invalid layer"..."sql= is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded."
```

Not sure what the problem is. The table is mentioned in the `geommetry_columns` table in PostGIS, but I can see a message entry in QGIS that says "No key field for given view". I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 and QGIS 1.8.0.

Comment: The problem seem to be related to the unique key field, you must have one. I don't know your data, maybe you could explain a bit more about what you want to achieve with your query. How are you opening the Layer in QGIS? Did you choose a key?

From what you described, only s.code can be use as unique key. Also, your municipio geometries will be repeated several times for each student, is that what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a spatial view in PostGIS and add it as a layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis)

Answer (score 9):

When you add a view from PostGIS to QGIS you have to specify the unique ID field.  Off to the right of the layer name will be a drop down where you can specify which field to use.  If you don't have a unique ID field you can create a fake ID field using the row_number() window function in the query that creates your view.

Comment: [This question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis) is related and gives more detail on selecting your unique ID field in the QGIS gui.

Comment: And [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/in-postgis-is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-with-a-unique-id) will give you more details on how to create a view with a unique id.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies.  Problem solved using the suggested function.

Answer (score 3):

Today I bumped into this error with a view created from a join between tables. It ended up having two unique fields that upset QGis. Initially the view was like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *
  FROM more_data m,
       node n   
 WHERE m.id_node = n.id;
```

This way there were two primary key fields in the view. Instead, I had to specify the resulting fields, in order to end up a single field candidate for unique identifier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT n.id,
       n.name,
       n.geom,
       m.type,
       m.other_stuff,
       m.more_stuff
  FROM more_data m,
       node n   
 WHERE m.id_node = n.id;
```