# Add a serial id column inside a view

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

Is it possible to create  a new id serial column inside a view? I need it to be able to add my view in postgis

I have made a full outer join on two tables 
I need a unique PK to load the view in QGIS. 
 Creating a id serial does not help in this case because it will become redundant once the two tables are joined.

This is my view:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
> SELECT 
>  table1.id
>  table1.name
>  table2.id
>  table2.street
> FROM table1
>  FULL OUTER JOIN table2
>  ON table1.id  = table2.id
> ```

I have seen some ROW_NUMBER examples but i dont know how to script it when I am using a join.[In PostGIS is it possible to create a View with a unique ID?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/in-postgis-is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-with-a-unique-id)

---

a final try before I find another direction to solve my problem. It is a try to use the row_number to create a unique column inside my VIEW. It looks daunting and it does not work.. probably not the best way of solving my problem (Iam not very experienced writing script yet.. but i give it a last try in case it is just a quick fix)

```
create view testView as (
    select
    row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 
 table1.id
 table1.name
 table2.id
 table2.street
FROM table1
 FULL OUTER JOIN table2
 ON table1.id  = table2.id) AS OID,
   table1.id
 table1.name
 table2.id
 table2.street
FROM table1
 FULL OUTER JOIN table2
 ON table1.id  = table2.id
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use uuid from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html and add it to the SELECT statement?

Comment: @geogrow can you verify your sql is correct? It looks like you're selecting from a table named columnA and you're pulling columns named table1, table2, table3...

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I wrote the sql incorrect. I hope it make more sense now. It is basically just a standard case of a full outer join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Row_Number works well if you have data returned that will allow you to order your results in a unique way, that is, duplicates in the library_na field below will give duplicate OID values from the row_number function:

```
create view testView as (
    select
    row_number() OVER(ORDER BY library_na DESC) AS OID
    , library_na
    , geom
    from public.libraries
)
```

which returns:

[image]

(sorry that screen cap looks bad...)

Comment: Thanks! I have used that in another situation, but I am confused to how I should write the script when i have already done a full outer join. I dont understand how I add the select row_number within the select of the columns.

Comment: @geogrow it should just be the first line in your SQL, or, you can wrap a sub-query around your join query and use the row_number there... see my comment above.

Comment: @geogrow did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes thanks eventually I did. I used a subquery to UNION 3 tables with similar structure and then used row_number to go on top of it to get a unique ID for each row.