# QGIS error message while running PostgreSQL code. WARNING Invalid PostgreSQL layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have run a code in pgAdmin it returns 43 rows of data. I took the same code ran it in QGIS and found the same row of data. However while trying to add the new data into the map QGIS comes with the error

> WARNING    Invalid PostgreSQL layer

I ran two forms of this code and both came back with the same error.

```
SELECT pin, ST_MakeValid(parcels.geom), ST_MakeValid(address_points.geom)
FROM   parcels
JOIN   address_points
       ON ST_Contains(parcels.geom,address_points.geom)
WHERE  class = 'CLUB';
```

or

```
SELECT pin
FROM   parcels
JOIN   address_points
       ON ST_Contains(ST_MakeValid(parcels.geom), ST_MakeValid(address_points.geom))
WHERE  class = 'CLUB';
```

What I am trying to do is select all the parcel that contains club within, and will add the new data to a new  table (create table AS ....).
I was making the map first to see if the data was good to map, which lead to the above error.

Comment: The first query returns two geometries, and the second returns none. Neither one is a valid layer. ST_MakeValid has a tangible cost -- best practice is to run it once in an UPDATE; then you don't need to slow down every query.

Comment: So maybe select all info contain to parcels.  select *

Comment: I have had this error more times. It may have to do with not having PK's in those tables.

Answer (score 2):

Normally that error occurs when QGIS cannot find a column with a unique "primary key". Ensure that the *pin* column has no duplicates, or add another field with a proper primary key.

See [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138594/add-a-serial-id-column-inside-a-view) for using the row number