SpatiaLite views in QGIS are not being mapped correctly
I've created a view in SpatiaLite, the unique id is made with
cast(row_number() over() as integer) as id
the geometry is made with
CastToMultiPolygon(st_union(geom)) as geom (it's a merging operation)
and the geometry is registered with
INSERT INTO "main"."geometry_columns" ("f_table_name", "f_geometry_column", "geometry_type", "coord_dimension", "srid", "spatial_index_enabled") VALUES ('table1', 'geom', '6', '2', '27700', '0');
The layer shows in the QGIS canvas and all the features show in the attribute table, but selecting features is messed up. there appears to be no relationship between the canvas location and the feature selected - I click on a feature on the canvas and a completely different feature somewhere else is selected.
On trying to zoom to the feature from the attribute table I get

WARNING    Zoom to feature id failed : Feature not found

and selection yields the spatialite error

WARNING    SQLite error: no such column: ROWID
SQL: SELECT 0,"description" FROM "table1" WHERE ROWID=7

As a test, I changed the query to declare the id column as "ROWID"
cast(row_number() over() as integer) as ROWID
then when I try to load the layer it won't load at all, complaining...

2024-07-26T13:10:36     WARNING    SQLite error: no such column: id
SQL: PRAGMA table_info("table1")

It seems the I'm not successfully telling QGIS what the unique id column is, but I cannot find any way to do so.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is completely expected behavior. Using row_number for a unique ID on anything but a materialized view will produce seemingly random results, because you've asked it to renumber every query, which means that any selection set based on a list of IDs will be useless in subsequent queries.

I don't understand your comment. I understand that a view with row_number() re-numbers each query, but all views change all data each query run, that's the point. Why would it suddenly become impossible to display this data (the unique_id), just because it changes each time the query is run? It seems counter-intuitive. Why not just run the query each time it's queried and display the results?

This https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/can-qgis-read-spatialite-views?rq=1 question posted this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/in-postgis-is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-with-a-unique-id upvoted answer which explicitly states "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_to_sort_by ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER..." as a means of getting a unique_id. What am I missing?

Keep it simple and use just select a.rowid AS rowid as in https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/Using-Views-Basic.pdf. The GDAL GeoPackage documentation has also a section about views https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html. If cast(row_number() over() as integer) as id happens to work otherwise it can easily break the connection from the main table to the spatial index table that is using the original ROWID.
